Seeking articles on closed-form formulas for specific partial fraction expansions
I'm currently researching a general closed-form formula, in terms of elementary functions, for functions that have the following type of partial fraction expansion:
$$\frac{1}{x^{p}}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(x-n)^{p}}+\frac{1}{(x+n)^{p}}\right).
$$
I would appreciate any references to articles, books, or papers that investigate or provide general closed-form formulas for such functions. Additionally, if you have insights or examples related to this type of expansion, please share them.

These are Hurwitz zeta functions,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(x-n)^{p}}+\frac{1}{(x+n)^{p}}\right)=(-1)^{-p} \zeta (p,1-x)+\zeta (p,1+x).$$
The Wikipedia entry for these special functions has quite an extensive list of formulas and pointers to the literature.
For integer $p$, as pointed out by Henri Cohen, this simplifies to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(x-n)^{p}}+\frac{1}{(x+n)^{p}}\right)=\frac{(-1)^{p-1} }{(p-1)!}\frac{\partial ^{p-1}}{\partial x^{p-1}}\frac{\pi  x \operatorname{cotan} (\pi  x)-1}{x}.$$

$\cot(\pi x)$ and derivatives.

indeed, for integer $p$.

I need references to articles that provide general closed-form formula, in terms of elementary functions ($\cos,\ \sin$).

there is no representation in terms of elementary functions for general $p\in\mathbb{R}$, only for integer $p$.

If you include the $n=0$ term as in the OP, the result is simpler: $\mathrm{p.v.}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{(x-n)^p}=\frac{(-1)^{p-1}\pi}{(p-1)!}(\cot\pi x)^{(p-1)}$ for integer $p\ge1$ (for $p\ge2$, the principal value is not needed as the sum is absolutely convergent).

@L.L To expand higher derivatives of $\cot\pi x$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/whats-the-generalisation-of-the-quotient-rule-for-higher-derivatives .
